# Java Code Compile Error

Tags: java, javac

I am trying to compile a 4KB Java game called "Left 4K Dead".. anyways, It will compile successfully with the `javac G.java` command, but when you go to run it using `java G` it spits back this error at me:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main`

Anyone know how to make this work? Thanks :)

Beginning of code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.util.*;

 public class G extends Applet implements Runnable
 {
private boolean[] k = new boolean[32767];
private int m;

public void start()
{
    enableEvents(AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK);
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public void run()
{
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(240, 240, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics ogr = image.getGraphics();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main

This exception indicates exactly what it states, there is no `main` method, so the program cannot start.

The issue with the Left 4k Dead code is it is an [applet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet). It expects to be compiled and then run from a webpage, not run from command line (i.e. you can't run it with the command `java`). If you wish to run it from the command line, you should look into a standalone [applet viewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppletViewer).

Comment: OH.. that would make sense.. in that case.. how do you run this in a web browser?

Comment: Java plugin for browsers deals with running it, specifically it runs it in its own sandbox process. The full details are a bit beyond the scope of this question, so if you are satisfied with the above answer for the current question, feel free to accept it and ask a new question about how to run it. With that said, the source code of the Left 4k Dead [website](http://www.mojang.com/notch/j4k/l4kd/) may give you some help.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Did some Google research on the subject.. think I got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

After compilation of the class, use

`appletviewer <class-name>`

to run it through the commandline since it is an `applet`.

**OR ELSE**

you can embed it in a browser as CodeMaker suggests.